# how to add a picture into wordpress witout uploading it on the backend?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a picture into the design of my blog and I've written it like this:

```
<img src="<?=TEMPLATEPATH; ?>/style/images/maskot.png" />
```

It won't display and I've made sure that the link is correct. What am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd view the source and see what the src is pointing to.

You may be able to amend the path by looking at the output.